# MySQL: Using Count to limit results?

Tags: mysql

Hi: I need a way to limit the results of a query with SUM or COUNT as if using limit. Is this possible? I have a table with questions and answers. Each entry is identified with "0" if question or "1" if response. Each answer have the questionID, so I can order by this field. I want to show the first 20 questions with all his answers without using limit, because using LIMIT 0,20 would be showing the first 20 entries no matter if they are questions or answers.

I would like to see some logic like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(IF(level = '0', 1,0)) AS MyCount FROM table 
WHERE MyCount<20 ORDER BY questionID,timestamp
```

how could I accomplish this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing a GROUP function (sum), try using HAVING instead of WHERE:

```
SELECT *, SUM(IF(level = '0 ', 1,0)) AS MyCount 
FROM   table 
HAVING MyCount < 20 
ORDER BY 
       questionID,timestamp
```

-- Edit --

Because you are storing two different types of data (response and question) in the same table,  you can try a self join (untested):

```
SELECT
    question.id AS question_id,
    question.name AS question_name,
    response.id AS response_id,
    response.name AS response_name        
FROM
    table AS question
JOIN
    table as response
ON
    question.id AND response.level = 1
WHERE 
    question.level = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a badly designed schema. have your questions in one table and your answers in another, make the question ID a foreign key on the answer table. chucking both of them together in the same table is why you now have this problem!

Comment: You're right, but the reason I did it this way is because I want to get the results in a single pass.